# Modify the limit of the y axis in plot.ACF (package nlme)

Tags: r, plot

I used the function plot.ACF (package nlme) to do a graph of the autocorrelations for model residuals.The problem is that the autocorrelations in the graph are very hard to read. How can I modify the limit of the y axis in the function plot.ACF ?

Here is my graph:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nlme:::plot.ACF` function has a hard-coded `ylim` assignment, so you have to modify the function slightly (the comment lines below are the only places I made changes).

```
my_acf_plot <- function (x, alpha = 0, xlab = "Lag", ylab = "Autocorrelation", 
                         grid = FALSE,
                         ylim = NULL,  ## add ylim
                         ...) 
{
    require("lattice")   ## for xyplot, panel.* function
    ## (unnecessary originally because the package imports 
    ##  the required functions)
    object <- x
    if (is.null(ylim)) ylim <- range(object$ACF)  ## set ylim if unset
    if (alpha) {
        assign("stdv", qnorm(1 - alpha/2)/sqrt(attr(object, "n.used")))
        stMax <- max(stdv)
        ylim <- c(min(c(-stMax, ylim[1])), max(c(ylim[2], stMax)))
    }
    assign("alpha", as.logical(alpha))
    assign("grid", grid)
    xyplot(ACF ~ lag, object, ylim = ylim, panel = function(x, 
        y, ...) {
        x <- as.numeric(x)
        y <- as.numeric(y)
        if (grid) 
            panel.grid()
        panel.xyplot(x, y, type = "h")
        panel.abline(0, 0)
        if (alpha) {
            llines(x, stdv, lty = 2)
            llines(x, -stdv, lty = 2)
        }
    }, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...)
}
```

Example:

```
library(nlme)
set.seed(101)
d <- data.frame(y=rnorm(50),x=1:50)    
my_acf_plot(ACF(gls(y~x,data=d)),ylim=c(-0.3,0.5))
```